# How to DRY (myself) in Django form for Create and Edit Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, dry

I created two forms in Django for the same model, named `AccountCreateForm` and `AccountEditForm`. The `Account` model has say three fields and each of them has a few form attributes such as `max_length`, `help_text`, `error_messages`. For example,

```
class AccountCreateForm(forms.Modelform):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label='Account Name', help_text='50 characters max', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the account name'})
    number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True, label='Phone Number', help_text='10-16 digits max', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the phone numbername'})
```

I want the user to be able to edit the existing accounts as well. So, I added another form for editing purposes as follow.

```
class AccountEditForm(forms.Modelform):
    name_error = { 'max_length': ("Name should be no longer than 50 characters."), 'required': ("Please enter the account name")}
    number_error = {'max_length': ("Phone number should be between 10-16 characters."),'min_length': ("Phone number should be between 10-16 characters."),'required': ("Please enter the phone number tied to the Twilio account")}

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label='Account Name', help_text='50 characters max', error_messages=name_error)
    number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=True, label='Phone Number', help_text='10-16 digits max', error_messages=number_error)
```

And my template for both `account_create.html` and `account_edit.html` share simple code like this:

```
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}({{ field.help_text }}):</label>
            <br />
            {{ field }}<br /><br />
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary done-btn" type="submit" value="Create New Account">
    </form>
```

It works fine and Django helps provide error messages and help texts fine. But, I feel like I'm repeating things here. I tried the approach suggested by [Django documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) like this:

```
class AccountEditForm(forms.Modelform):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('name', 'number')
        labels = {'name' : _('Account Name'), 'number': _('Phone Number')}
        error_messages = {
                'name': {
                    'max_length': _("Name should be no longer than 50 characters."), 'required': ....}
```

and so on. But then if I intentionally left, say the `name` field, blank in edit form, Django doesn't show error. The only way it'll show error seems the first approach. Is there something that I can do to improve the code quality (that is, to be not repetitive)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two ways to accomplish this:-

1) Make the name field required inside the model by adding 'blank=False'.

```
    name = models.CharField(blank=False)
```

2) If you don't want to modify blank setting for your fields inside models (doing so will break normal validation in admin site), you can do the following in your Form class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AccountEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields["name"].required = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I thought assigning like this in the model.py file: `forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)` is sufficient? Why do we need to repeat that in the Form class?

Comment: The answer was for your second case. Also adding required=True doesn't work on form. To add form level validation, you need to add blank=false to your model field declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer.